# Qt, show QListView as QCompleter

Tags: qt, qlistview

I was trying to show my own `QListView` everytime a text in a particular `QLineEdit` had changed in the same way `QCompleter` shows its own.

I was doing some tests, connecting the `textChanged()` `SIGNAL` from `QLineEdit` to the `QlistView::show()` `SLOT` but it just appears for 0.1 seconds and then hides again.

How can make `QListView` visible while Im editing text in `QLineEdit` and hide it when I "exit" from it ( from `QLineEdit` )?

Comment: "How can I achieve what I want? " Very broad question. Maybe you should sit back and consider defining "show my own `QListView`" a little better.

Comment: I edited the question, it should be more clear now

Comment: there's focus SIGNALs